# C# Twilio retrieve composition media

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to download a composition media file into my hard drive using the following code:

```
try
{
    var uri = "https://video.twilio.com/v1/Compositions/" + sid + "/Media?Ttl=6000";

    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_apiKeySid + ":" + _apiKeySecret)));
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    var responseBody = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    var mediaLocation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseBody)["redirect_to"];

    new WebClient().DownloadFile(mediaLocation, "D:\\test.mp4");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var temp = ex.Message;
}
```

But every time I get an exception with this message: "The remote server returned an error: (302) FOUND."

Note that this method is called after Twilio calls my `StatusCallback` method which I've set when creating a new composition using `CompositionResource.CreateAsync` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the problem was that the request was being redirected to a new location, so all I had to do was to allow redirects for the request and then download the file by copying the stream object to a file, like this:

```
        var uri = "https://video.twilio.com/v1/Compositions/" + sid + "/Media?Ttl=6000";

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_apiKeySid + ":" + _apiKeySecret)));
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        var responseBody = (await request.GetResponseAsync()).GetResponseStream();

        using (var fs = File.Create(@"D:\test.mp4"))
        {
            responseBody.CopyTo(fs);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

302 Found means that the resource that you are looking for has been moved to the different URL. Check the [Location Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) of the response to see what is the new URL.

[302 Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status
>   response code indicates that the resource requested has been
>   temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header. A browser
>   redirects to this page but search engines don't update their links to
>   the resource (in 'SEO-speak', it is said that the 'link-juice' is not
>   sent to the new URL).

Comment: Could you please describe to me what changes should I make to the piece of code in my question to make it work?